# DevOps Powershell step calls bat file successfully but returns 1

Tags: powershell, batch-file, yaml, devops

I'm calling a bat-file from a step in my yaml file. The bat is located locally on the PC where the build agent is.
The bat is called successfully. It changes the PATH-variable and runs a program afterwards. The program runs successfully however when finished the build step is still marked as unsuccessful because

> [error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.

As background information as to why I'm using a bat-file instead of ps1: I'm migrating our current build and it runs over a central bat-file. I don't want to change it.

Is there an environment variable I can change or anything else I can do to ensure the powershell returns 0 instead of 1?

Comment: You've mentioned four main components to your question, a `.yaml` file, a `.bat` file, a `.ps1` file and a returned error message, _from an unspecified one of those_. Your question is unclear because you've provided less that 25% of the information we need to help you with your issue.

Comment: Actually 25% of the information seemed to be enough because I got help.

Comment: Just because you got lucky on this occasion, does not absolve you from not following the help and guidelines available at [ask]. I have additionally rolled back your edit, because the question area is not where you should be repeating the accepted response or providing updates after having received it. Please do that either under the accepted answer or add an answer yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered changing the batch file exit code?

> Exit codes for batch files
>
> Use the command EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL% at the end of the batch file to
>   return the error codes from the batch file
>
> - EXIT /B at the end of the batch file will stop execution of a batch file.
> - use EXIT /B < exitcodes > at the end of the batch file to return custom return codes.
> - Environment variable %ERRORLEVEL% contains the latest errorlevel in the batch file,which is the latest error codes from the last command executed. To know about Environment variable see the below note.
>
> Note: Environment variables are a set of dynamic named values that can
>   affect the way, running processes will behave on a computer. For
>   example, an environment variable with a standard name can store the
>   location that a particular computer system uses to store user profile
>   this may vary from one computer system to another.
>
> In the batch file , it is always a good practice to use environment
>   variables instead of constant values. Since the same variable get
>   expanded to different values on different computers.
>
> Example:
>
> Batch file for Copying File to a Folder
>
> ```
> md "C:manageengine" 
> copy "\\sharename\foldername\samplefile.txt" "C:\manageengine" 
> exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%
> ```

https://www.manageengine.com/products/desktop-central/returning-error-code-on-scripts-how-to.html

**EDIT:** Some more thoughts about the problem- The batch file probably returned 1 as an exit code because one of the commands or programs used within it returned some kind of error code (or at least didn't return 0 exit code).
for summing up, your question was not very clear mainly because you didn't separate all the factors and variable withing your problem, thus not knowing where the problem is.
Force changing the exit code isn't the right way to fix your problem.

Comment: Please avoid posting link-only answers. They'll become useless if the referenced page disappears (and yes, that happens more frequently than you might expect). If you're referencing an external source, please include the gist of that reference in your answer.